# Creación de un modelo de subasta al estilo de oferta máxima de eBay

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de trabajar con algunos conceptos de modelos de casas de subastas,estoy programando en PHP.

Ya utilizo el orden en el `$oferta = $row3["oferta"];` para definir la oferta más alta, pero me preguntaba si hay una manera simple de definir max_bid y el resultado para el usuario es lo que parece un sistema de "oferta inteligente", al estilo eBay.

```php
$bid1 = 9000  # oferta máxima para el objeto bid1
$bid2 = 6000  # oferta máxima para el objeto bid2
$bid3 = 9500  # oferta máxima para el objeto bid3
$starting_price = 5000  # precio de salida de la subasta Ejemplo
```

Cuando se coloca bid1 (lo que indica que la oferta inteligente más alta debe ser 9000), el precio de subasta actual debe permanecer en 5000, ya que no hay otras ofertas en el artículo.

Cuando se coloca bid2, el precio de subasta actual debería aumentar a 6001 (ya que bid1 es aún más alto)

Cuando se coloca bid3, el precio de subasta actual debería aumentar a 9001 (superando bid1 y convirtiéndose en el mejor postor actual).

Si alguien tiene alguna idea sobre la mejor manera de abordar esto, me encantaría escucharla.

El sitio funciona básicamente como eBay, donde si el artículo está actualmente en $10 y el "postor A" ofrece $50, el precio del artículo permanecerá en $10 hasta que un segundo postor haga una oferta más alta. Digamos que el "postor B" hace una oferta de $40, entonces el artículo estaría en ($40 + incremento). El incremento es, dependiendo de la subasta, una cantidad fija (digamos $5) o un porcentaje del precio actual.

// Paso 1: obtenga el precio de subasta actual, la cantidad del postor más alto y el tipo de incremento de la base de datos o variables
`$currentAuctionPrice =` // Recuperar el precio de subasta actual de la base de datos o configurarlo como una variable
$highestBidderAmount = // Recupera el monto del mejor postor de la base de datos o configúralo como una variable
$incrementType = // Recupera el tipo de incremento de la base de datos o configúralo como una variable

// Paso 2: Obtener el monto de la oferta presentado por el postor
`$bidAmount =` // Recuperar el monto de la oferta presentada por el postor

// Paso 3: Determinar el incremento basado en el tipo de incremento

````
    $increment = 5; // Establecer la cantidad de incremento fijo
} elseif ($incrementType === 'percentage') {```
    // Calcular el incremento porcentual basado en el precio de subasta actual
   ``` $percentage = 0.05; // Establecer el valor de incremento porcentual (por ejemplo, 5%)
    $increment = $currentAuctionPrice * $percentage;
} demás {```
    // Manejar otros tipos de incrementos si es necesario
  ```  $increment = 0; // Establecer un valor de incremento predeterminado
}```

// Paso 4: Verifique si el monto de la oferta es mayor que el precio actual de la subasta más el incremento
```if ($bidAmount  > ($currentAuctionPrice + $increment)) {
    $currentAuctionPrice = $bidAmount  - $increment; // Actualizar el precio de subasta actual
    $cantidad del postor más alto = $bidAmount; // Actualizar la cantidad del mejor postor
}```

// Paso 5: actualice el precio de subasta actual y el monto del postor más alto en la base de datos o variables
// Guardar ```$currentAuctionPrice y $highestBidderAmount``` como los nuevos valores
````

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. Es necesario que indiques el problema concreto que tienes con el código y qué código estás implementando para resolver este problema. Eso no quita que alguien pueda aconsejarte, según qué casos, mejores prácticas, pero eso cuando se haya entendido el problema y se tenga a la vista lo que estás implementando.

Comment: No es claro qué problema tienes implementando lo que nos estás explicando. Nos mencionas código de forma anecdótica (_ya utilizo el orden en el `$oferta = $row3`_, donde yo no sé qué sea nada de eso) pero no es claro cuál es el código que quieres modificar. Faltan muchos detalles y aclaraciones (y un problema puntual a resolver).

Comment: ¿Por qué no metes todas las pujas en un array y utilizas la función `max()`?